# Neo4j and django models

Tags: python, django, nosql, neo4j

So, I'm looking into the Django and Neo4j integration, but there's not much about it out there ... What I want to know is if I have a model like the one here: 
If I want to add a new property to a model, it would be as simple as doing:

```
node.setProperty( "newProperty", "something" );
```

??

Moreover, all the queries in django would work ? How is the traversing made ?

I would appreciate any response 
:D

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've been working on updating the Neo4j/Django integration to work with [neo4j-rest-client](http://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client) - the fruits of our labor are [on GitHub](http://github.com/scholrly/neo4django), with some quick comments on my [blog](https://mattluongo.com/post/when-to-open-source).

There are some pros and cons to our integration. The most obviously impacting is our use of a REST client- you get to use a remote database, while losing quite a bit, performance-wise. OTOH, the integration works alongside a relational database, so you can still use django.contrib stuff that relies on the original ORM, and it handles indexing and query sets pretty nicely.

To do what you want above using neo4django, you'd simply get the neo4j-rest-client based node from the model instance, and have at it.

```
model_instance.node['newProperty'] = 'something'
```

We're still cranking on making the integration more dynamic, supporting traversals/etc in a Pythonic way, and (currently most important) improving the performance. If you're interested, I'd love feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen Tobias's blog [post about Django integration](http://journal.thobe.org/2009/12/seamless-neo4j-integration-in-django.html)? It's kinda old now, but still relevant. Plus there are [examples](https://svn.neo4j.org/components/neo4j.py/trunk/src/examples/python/djangosites/) you can check out too.

Comment: Yep, I saw it, but, as you said, it's kind of old, so I was not sure if anything has changed or upgraded. I'll check the examples, yes ...

Comment: But, still I don't get if I can add a new property or not .. Would this be as simple as edit my models.py ?

Comment: It's been a while since I tinkered, but it should be, yes. I thought you were talking about dynamically adding stuff to Nodes, rather than extending the Model

Comment: First of all, I thought about it as so, but I guess that, if I want to continue using Django, that's the way to add new "information" to entities. Well .. Not seeing much advantage of using Neo4j with django, as the entities become attached to models "types" and traversing doesn't seem so well implemented. Not telling the difficulties to get it working .. Am I wrong ?

Comment: You're right- the Django ORM is all about creating schemas, so using a Django-style ORM for Neo4j tends to cast unnatural constraints (like typing and schemas) on the database. You could always just use Django with the new neo4j.py, or neo4j-rest-client, and totally eschew the ORM. If it isn't helping you in your domain, why use it? That said, see my answer below.