# What's the best way to access Neo4j from Django?

Tags: django, neo4j

it seems that i found something that let me confused; i've found two Neo4j to download to python, the first one is:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4j-embedded

and the second one is:

- https://svn.neo4j.org/components/neo4j.py/trunk/

what's the difference between the two? the first one seems to be big (size), so does this mean that if i use it i'll not need the neo4j community release (milestone)?

when i've installed the first one, and tried to test a django example, it seems that the directory named "model" https://svn.neo4j.org/components/neo4j.py/trunk/src/main/python/neo4j/model/ is missing? so what's the difference, and who will be better to use with Django?

and what about that one?

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4django/

Comment: i dont see why downvoting without any arguments?

Comment: I think the question needs to be cleaned up a bit- thus the downvotes.  You don't really mean "which Neo4j", for example, you mean "which Python binding for Neo4j works well with Django?".

Comment: yes, my apologies, my english is bad, and my dictionary is so limited to find words ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm part of the team that began updating [neo4django](http://github.com/scholrly/neo4django) from Tobias's original integration, but I'll try to be fair =)

You skipped another important library- [neo4j-rest-client](http://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client), the Python REST binding. neo4django is based on this library, and shares a bunch of its [advantages and disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866635/neo4j-and-django-models/7761360#7761360). In particular, a REST client will always be slower than a native client, but it allows the easy use of a remote database.

neo4django is a pretty tight integration with Django. It's [very similar](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/blob/master/README.rst) to the standard ORM, and has some cool goodies like queries with index support and working alongside a relational DB. I like it alot, but if you aren't using a remote database, the performance penalty might be too high. I'm working on it, though, so [keep posted](http://github.com/scholrly/neo4django)!

I believe the svn link above (https://svn.neo4j.org/components/neo4j.py/trunk/) is the old native Python binding. The new one is way better from what I've seen (less of a headache, updated), so unless you want to give the old bundled Django integration a try, it'd be easier to avoid it.

The first link (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4j-embedded) is the newer integration. I don't think 'model' is included in the distro, because it doesn't yet come with Django integration. If you need serious performance and you're okay with dropping the Django-style data-definition-language, it's the way to go.

In the future, I hope to get neo4django working with the native and REST clients... we'll see what happens!

Comment: ahhhh!!!! thank you for the answer, that what i'm looking for!!! you've arranged some unsorted ideas :)

thank you again
Edit: thank you again for the Neo4j-rest-client, with that, it will be easier since it will use the REST interface as Django Admin :)

Comment: The project is not longer =(

Comment: Indeed, I've moved on and don't have time to maintain the project. PRs are always welcome to get us up to date, though!