# ORM with Graph-Databases like Neo4j in Python

Tags: python, orm, neo4j, graph-databases, bulbs

i wonder wether there is a solution (or a need for) an ORM with Graph-Database (f.e. Neo4j). I'm tracking relationships (A is related to B which is related to A via C etc., thus constructing a large graph) of entities (including additional attributes for those entities) and need to store them in a DB, and i think a graph database would fit this task perfectly.

Now, with sql-like DBs, i use sqlalchemyś ORM to store my objects, especially because of the fact that i can retrieve objects from the db and work with them in a pythonic style (use their methods etc.).

Is there any object-mapping solution for Neo4j or other Graph-DB, so that i can store and retrieve python objects into and from the Graph-DB and work with them easily?

Or would you write some functions or adapters like in the python sqlite documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#letting-your-object-adapt-itself) to retrieve and store objects?

Comment: I think there might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866635/neo4j-and-django-models that is interesting here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple choices in Python out there right now, based on databases' REST interfaces.

As I mentioned in the link @Peter provided, we're working on neo4django, which updates the old Neo4j/Django integration. It's a good choice if you need complex queries and want an ORM that will manage node indexing as well- or if you're already using Django. It works very similarly to the native Django ORM. Find it on [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4django/0.1.4) or [GitHub](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django).

There's also a more general solution called [Bulbflow](http://bulbflow.herokuapp.com/) that is supposed to work with any graph database supported by Blueprints. I haven't used it, but from what I've seen it focuses on domain modeling - Bulbflow already has working relationship models, for example, which we're still working on- but doesn't much support complex querying (as we do with Django querysets + index use). It also lets you work a bit closer to the graph.

Comment: Bulbflow seems quite nice, i´ll have a look at it. Is it bound to Flask etc. or can you use it "standalone" ?(i think so). Neo4j Django looks good, too, but i´d like to have a plattform/framework-independent or standalone-solution (which could be bound to a framework later on).

Comment: From what I understand Bulbflow can be used standalone. @versae's answer seems to agree.

And because I'm always selling- despite the name, so can neo4django- it has a few code dependencies on Django but doesn't require you to use the actual framework :)

Comment: Answer is not relevant anymore: both neo4django and bulbflow are abandoned. A more recent OGM (Object-Graph-Mapper) is neomodel, and django-neomodel if you're using Django.

Answer (score 13):

Shameless plug... there is also my own ORM which you may also want to checkout: https://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel

It's built on top of py2neo, using cypher and rest API calls under hood, i.e no dependency on gremlin.

Comment: Note: neomodel is not built on top of py2neo anymore, but on the official neo4j-driver.

Comment: Wow, I went in expecting the repo to be completely deprecated, but it looks like it's had a lot of work put in, kudos!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you could take a look on [Bulbflow](http://bulbflow.herokuapp.com/), that allows to create models in Django, Flask or Pyramid. However, it works over a [REST client](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4jrestclient/1.5.0) instead of the [python-binding](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/neo4j-embedded/1.5) provided by Neo4j, so perhaps it's not as fast as the native binding is.