# Neo4j and Django, make a Graph for recommendations

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgresql, neo4j

We are using `Django` for our backend REST API and PostgreSQL as DB. Need to build a `User` graph which has `Story` as a property for recommendation system. I came across `Neo4jDjango`. [Many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866635/neo4j-and-django-models) here seem to suggest this lib. But the last commit on this was [3 years before.](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django)

Is there a upto date lib I can use to seamlessly itegerate it with `Django`. Using `Python2.7` and `Django1.11` along side with PostgreSQL, want to use `Neo4j` just for graph querying.

It should be able to support realtime db sync, i.e. with each row update in a model a node is added in graph.

Answer (score 1):

The [Neo4j web site](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/) shows some alternatives to work with Python and Neo4j. Take a look:

**Neo4j Python Driver:** The Neo4j Python driver is officially supported by Neo4j and connects to the database using the binary protocol. It aims to be minimal, while being idiomatic to Python. ([Githib repo](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver), Last commit 3 days ago)

**Py2neo:** Py2neo is a client library and comprehensive toolkit for working with Neo4j from within Python applications and from the command line. The core library has no external dependencies and has been carefully designed to be easy and intuitive to use. ([Github repo](https://github.com/nigelsmall/py2neo), Last commit on 15 Dec 2016)

**Neomodel:** An Object Graph Mapper built on top of the Neo4j python driver. Familiar Django style node definitions with a powerful query API, thread safe and full transaction support. A Django plugin django_nemodel is also available. ([Github repo](http://github.com/robinedwards/neomodel), Last commit on 9 Jun)

**Neo4jRestClient**: The main goal of neo4j-rest-client was to enable Python programmers already using Neo4j locally through python-embedded, to use the Neo4j REST server. So the syntax of neo4j-rest-client’s API is fully compatible with python-embedded. However, a new syntax is introduced in order to reach a more pythonic style and to enrich the API with the new features the Neo4j team introduces. ([Github repo](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client), Last commit on 14 Jun 2016)

As you can see, the Neo4j Python Driver is the most up to date.

Comment: Does `Neo4j Python Driver` support realtime db signal processing?